# Java jsoup date parsing exception

Tags: java, date, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get date from website using jsoup, but after parsing string(Cyrillic characters) and converting it to the date format I'm getting an exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1 апреля 2018"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.convertDate(HtmlParser.java:116)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.getDate(HtmlParser.java:105)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.createJob(HtmlParser.java:64)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.getAllJobs(HtmlParser.java:53)
at ru.skilanov.io.jobsparser.HtmlParser.main(HtmlParser.java:45)
```

Converting method:

```
private Date convertDate(String date){
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String str = String.format("%s %s", date, year);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", new Locale("ru", "RU"));
try {
    return format.parse(str);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

Date parsing method:

```
private Date getDate(Element element){
String date = element.select(DATE_QUERY).text();
return convertDate(date);
}
```

**UPDATE** Solved.

I changed covertDate method by spliting input parameter:

```
    private Date convertDate(String date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String str = String.format("%s %s %s", getDay(date), getMonth(date), year);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
    try {
        return format.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

getDay method:

```
    private String getDay(String date) {
    return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[0];
}
```

getMonth method:

```
    private String getMonth(String date) {
    return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[1];
}
```

Comment: what `date` return ?

Comment: date return String "1 апреля" - it's day and month without year.

Comment: I test your code, and it work fine with me!

Comment: amps please take a look at [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Comment: Ok, if I write a date in convertDate by myself(for example String str = "1 апреля 2018";) and convert it, it works , but if i get a date from get date and concatinate it with year it doesn't work.

Comment: Then its give you some special characters ! check the input carfully

Comment: then what was the problem?

Comment: I changed covertDate method by spliting input parameter, see my post I edited it.

Comment: Sam, please consider, are this question and its solution likely to help other readers in the future? If no, please delete the question (you have a delete link under the question). If yes, please post the solution as an answer under the question because that is where everyone is going to check for an answer (not inside the question, they likely won’t find it there). Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Ole V.V., thank you for your answer, i can mark it as solution only tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I changed covertDate method by spliting input parameter:

```
private Date convertDate(String date) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String str = String.format("%s %s %s", getDay(date), getMonth(date), year);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
try {
    return format.parse(str);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}
getDay method:

```
private String getDay(String date) {
return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[0];
```

}
getMonth method:

```
private String getMonth(String date) {
return date.split("[\\u00A0\\s]+")[1];
```

}